# using | filter in ng-options in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I'm pretty new to angular.
I want to have a where clause in my ng-options  like this :

```
select * from currencies where  currency.code in ( 'usd' , 'cad')

<select ng-model="selectedCurrency" ng-options="currency.Name for currency in Currencies | filter:currency.code = 'usd' track by currency.ID">
    <option value="">-- select a currency--</option>
</select>
```

I could do it for only one code but I want to select it from an array of two or more !

Comment: please show your code

Comment: I want to filter by two currencies : USD and CAD

Comment: Read the [documentation of the filter filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). It accepts a predicate function as argument. Implement a function that returns true if the currency code is one of the accpted ones, and pass that function to the filter.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
ng-options="currency.Name for currency in Currencies track by currency.ID | filter: {code: 'usd'}"
```

To search multiple values you can use a function:

```
$scope.filterCurrencyCodes = function(currency) {
    return (['usd', 'cad'].indexOf(currency.code) !== -1);
};

ng-options="currency.Name for currency in Currencies track by currency.ID | filter: filterCurrencyCodes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
ng-options="currency.Name for currency in Currencies track by currency.ID | filter: filterCurrency"
```

And then create a method for evaluate the currency code:

```
$scope.filterCurrency= function(currency){
   if(currency.code == 'USD' || currency.code == 'CAD'){
       return true;
   }
   return false;
};
```